# htaccess redirect to "https://www."

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ssl

I would like to make a redirection to https://www.

Which means that:

```
http:// --> https://www.
http://www. --> https://www.
https:// --> https://www.
https://www. --> no redirection
```

I tried plenty of things but never reached that goal.

**my current `.htacces`:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem is that it doesn't redirect to `www`. So I tried to put that before :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that made a redirection curl so shut my site down.

PS: I'm on symfony

Does someone have the magic solution ?
Thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules to enforce both `https and`www`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did but it's not taken in account because I don't have 15 likes.. sorry

Comment: No you don't need 15 reps to accept an answer that is for upvoting. You can mark the answer as accepted **by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer** and it will turn green