# redirect from https:// to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, https, http-redirect

Given is my **.htaccess** rules set.

I am able to redirect

**`http://example.com`**   to `https://www.example.com`
**`http://www.example.com`**   to `https://www.example.com`

But
**`https://example.com`** is not redirecting to `https://www.example.com`

Giving **This Connection is Untrusted** error on Firefox

@Tobias K. **google.com** `Subject Alt Name` is

```
Not Critical
DNS Name: www.google.com
```

But still it redirect from `https://google.com` to `https:www.google.com`

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1.php [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I am using vhost configuration on apache 2.2.34 (AWS linux)

Given is my vhost config
**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.com

  ServerAlias www.example.com example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com

  ServerAdmin itsupport@example.com

  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/logs/example.com/error_log

  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/new_cert/www_parentcompany_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/www_parentcompany_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ec2-user/new_cert/DigiCertCA.crt
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know if I have missed something.

Tried given solution but no luck.
[htaccess redirect to "https://www."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068570/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)
[htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www?rq=1)

Thanks.

Comment: Your certificate is probably only valid on `www.example.com`. So you get the warning when you try to serve a site (or just a redirect) on `example.com` with it. If you can re-issue the cert, include both names as `subjectAltName`s.

Comment: This has already been explained - in more depth that I could above - here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931004/7362396

Comment: @TobiasK. **google.com** `Subject Alt Name` is  

    Not Critical
    DNS Name: www.google.com

But still it redirect from `https://google.com` to `https:www.google.com`

Comment: I understand that your main domain is with *www*. You still need a valid certificate for the non-*www* variant if you want to avoid the "untrusted"-error on the redirect. Like described in my linked answer or @Ufuk Tan answer.

Comment: Is this problem solved? If it's not, is the `https://www.example.com` accessible?

Comment: Problem not solved. Yes, `https://www.example.com` is accessible as mentioned in original question.

Comment: If you can share vhost config for SSL `(*:443)`, I can understand the problem better.

Comment: @UfukTan we dont have `(*:443)` listing in vhost.conf. I have updated question with ssl.conf entries

Comment: This is what i asking for. Now i don't see nothing wrong with your apache configuration. If SSL certificate doesn't valid for non-www domain, problem probably is this. By the way, some CA's cover the SSL for non-www, some not. Google probably have wildcard certificate which is valid for *.google.com and google.com. If you want to try apache config, I'll update my answer. But i think the problem is most likely SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be occurred by two reasons:

### 1. From SSL cerficate:

Since you said:

> Giving **This Connection is Untrusted** error on Firefox

Some CA's automatically add example.com version with www.example.com, some not. Make sure your SSL certificate valid for both **www.example.com** and **example.com**

You can check your certificate with this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

*You can see google has *.google.com and google.com*

### 2. From Apache virtual hosts:

According to this...

> I am able to redirect
>
> http://example.com to https://www.example.com
>
> http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

...and this...

> But https://example.com is not redirecting to https://www.example.com

...I'm thinking, you accomplished the configuration for http successfully, since both

- http://www.example.com
- http://example.com

are redirecting to https://www.example.com.

But redirecting from **https://example.com** to **https://www.example.com** must be specified at htps (:443) virtual host configuration. Those rules cannot be determined by http (:80) virtual host config file.

For achieve this problem you have to add those rewrite rule to *ssl.conf* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]
```

So, it could be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/new_cert/www_parentcompany_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/www_parentcompany_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ec2-user/new_cert/DigiCertCA.crt
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```